# About facebook policy for mobile apps using ad-platform

Tags: facebook, policy, ads

I want to use Facebook API on iOS.
For example, game ranking for FB users, or posting their recording(like high score).
And I have plan to make iOS game (native) for free with ad platforms (like iAd, AdMob, Tapjoy...)

But, I found bellow limitation for facebook platform.

> Facebook Platform Policies
>
> III. Content A. General
>
> a. You must not include advertisements, cross-promote other
>   applications, or provide web search functionality in content
>   distributed through Facebook social channels.

Is it means that I can't use ad-platforms for iOS native apps(games) using facebook API?
And I can't advertising other apps (like cross-promote) on iOS native apps(games)?
(And I can't found how to ask for this.)

Comment: you should better ask this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.